# Python Conditional Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I have a `dataframe` 1 with customer info, 16 columns of different metrics.  (example columns named "Subscription Price", "Has Internet (1=y/0=n")

I have a second `dataframe` 2 with 16 rows that correspond to the 16 column names in df1. The second column of `df2[ChangeValues]` is a number.

What I want to do, is loop through df1 for each row in df2 and see if the values equal.
`df[Has Cable] value =df2[df2[Has Cable`] value. If they do then do nothing, else change it to the `df2` corresponding value

Basically if they don't have cable then I want to change the value to 1, if the have cable I don't care and skip the record.

Output any that change to a new data frame.

Then repeat for the next row of `df2`
Help or guidance please

Comment: Could you provide your attempt in code?

Comment: please provide an explicit and reproducible example of input and the matching expected output

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: This seems like a pivot + join. You shouldn't need a loop.